# Kivy for Python - Attempt to load audio via SoundLoader - GStreamer fails to load plugins

Tags: python, kivy, gstreamer

I am trying to play music in Kivy App. Widget appears with button, after clicking on button music is playing, but (!) after music ends, App becomes "not responding" and message pops up "Python stopped working". Error code in debug screen:

```
C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/u6030283/Dropbox/PycharmProjects/PingPong/Test.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\u6030283\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-04-26_13.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [AudioGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.14.1.0
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_gstplayer, audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libass-9.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libass-9.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libgstassrender.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libgstassrender.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libgstpango.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libgstpango.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libgstrsvg.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libgstrsvg.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libharfbuzz-0.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libharfbuzz-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(python.exe:14084): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\librsvg-2-2.dll': 'C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\share\gstreamer\bin\librsvg-2-2.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I see 8 such error messages for different dll-s

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader,Sound
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:'song'
            on_press:root.plays()
''')

class MenuPage(Screen):
    M = SoundLoader.load('bubbles.mp3')

    def plays(self):
        if MenuPage.M.state == 'stop':
            MenuPage.M.play()
        else:
            MenuPage.M.stop()


sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuPage(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Also: I am using latest versions of Kivy and Python

Comment: Are you sure that's an application-halting error? Can you post the full log?

Comment: Please see in code section, I have posted full log